# Java Window Size Limitations on OSX Yosemite (10.10.5)

Tags: java, macos, window

I am attempting to resize a window from a Java application to span 8 connected monitors. All monitors are the exact same Dell monitor with 2560 X 1600 resolution each. The monitors are laid out so that there are 4 across and 2 down. This means that the total resolution across all 8 monitors is 10240 X 3200. However, no Java application seems capable of expanding past about 4096 X 3200. Since I know Java applications were able to scale across all 8 monitors before I updated the system to OSX, it makes me wonder if Java doesn't play nicely with OSX.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Anyone know how to fix it or if I can?

**Previous Findings**

- I know that the new OS has an options in System Preferences to make a multi-monitor display continuous. I have already done this.
- There are ways get the entire screen resolution dynamically in Java, which I found references to previously on StackOverflow. The original documentation is on java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration. While this seems to be able to determine what the total screen resolution should be and despite me using setBounds (or setSize) to make the application be that size, it will not work. I also tried statically inputting the desired dimensions and saw no difference than doing so dynamically. Even simple programs cannot be manually resized beyond the 4096 X 3200 size. (Sample program code is provided below.)
- I also know that OSX doesn't seem to like to have windows span multiple displays if the upper boundary of the window is moved too close to the top of a monitor or too close to the boundary between an upper monitor or a lower monitor. When this happens, OSX automatically scales the window so that it only takes up the hight of one monitor, and the window is placed at the top of the nearest monitor. This is not just with Java applications, but with any application and is simply how OSX operates. This also means that attempting to start an application that is higher than one screen will trigger this behavior as well. For my purposes right now, that is ok (even though not preferable); I just want to be able to span all 8 monitors, even if I have to manually resize the window.
- My belief that this issue is only with Java applications is based on the fact that three separate Java applications (including the sample one below) have the same issue. However, other applications on the machine, like Google Chrome, seem to have no problem spanning all 8 monitors.
- Because of the Dock at the bottom of one of the monitors and the menu at the top of another, I may not be able to get the full hight of 3200 pixels. That's fine; I just want to get as close to the 10240 X 3200 window size as possible. (So, right now, the width is the real issue.)

**System Details**
OS: OSX Yosemite (10.10.5),
Processor: 2X2.26 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon,
Memory: 16 BG,
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 512 MB

**Sample Java Program**

```
import javax.swing.*;

class WindowTest extends JFrame {
  public WindowTest() {
    setSize(10240, 3200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    WindowTest w = new WindowTest();
    w.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a very specific technical question. If you don't get answers in the first couple days, consider a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question, and nice SSCCE but I am unable to test the following code since my machine only has one display port, but I hope this may be of some help.

The call to `setSize(10240, 3200)` is often ignored, the javadoc tells us

> The method changes the geometry-related data. Therefore, **the native windowing system may ignore such requests, or it may modify the requested data**, so that the Window object is placed and sized in a way that corresponds closely to the desktop settings.

Instead I suggest using both of the following to try and force a size, and call `pack()` later:

```
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10240, 3200));
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10240, 3200));
```

In addition to this you can and should specify the JFrame location relative to the left/top most screen, something a little like this: (Edit: Updated to reflect the comments and added `pack()` where needed)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class WindowTest extends JFrame
{
    public WindowTest()
    {
        setLocation(0, 0);

        //Set your window to a specific size, we can force this by calling pack() later
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10240, 3200));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10240, 3200));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set cross-platform Java L&F (also called "Metal")
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            //Do nothing, the progam will default to automatic system assigned L&F
            System.out.println("Failed to set L&F to \"Metal\": "+e.getMessage());
        }
        WindowTest w = new WindowTest();
        w.setVisible(true);
        //Then try pack() to force your window size, and hopefully ignore OS sizing
        w.pack();
    }
}
```

This should achieve the frame size you want.

Comment: I tried using this to see what would happen, and I got a runtime error. So I tried just adding the setMinimumSize and setPreferred size to the test file and moved the setLocation to the top. Just doing that, I got the same error:

2015-09-03 13:31:45.250 java[867:110513] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:298)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:98)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:324)
...'

Comment: I tried using smaller sizes and commenting in/out setPreferredSize and setMinimumSize. It seems that setMinimumSize is what is causing the error. I used setLocation(800, 800), setMinumumSize(new Dimension(9000, 1500)), and setPreferredSize(new Dimension(9460, 2600)). Although this also produced errors, the window was displayed on screen, but at a smaller size than what I specified. After moving the window, I attempted to resize it, and the window jumped to a larger size. It appeared to be the preferred size that I gave it, but I couldn't change the window size. (Trying to only moved it.)

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be related to the default Look and Feel that is auto assigned on OSX. Add a code snippet to set your app to the Metal L&F instead, it should fix the error completely. In addition: The reason window resizing wont work is because of the way we have set the sizes, one way to get around this by listening for the resize event and then change the `PreferredSize` and `MinimumSize` to match the new window size, alternately there may be a better solution than what I have offered that does not use setMinimumSize and will avoid the issue.

Comment: I tried listening to the componentResized event. Setting the PreferredSize and MinimumSize to the new window size had no effect; I still can't scale the window up the way I want to. Also, the Metal L&F is the default, and I am not setting it differently for Macs. (I do for Windows.)

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the earlier comments and I have added the missing call to `pack()` the JFrame, can you give it a shot and see if you get the same results. The L&F part may be necessary because some IDE's will use a different L&F than the metal default.

Comment: Your window resizing question is better to be asked as a new question, rather than in comments. However you should be able to increase or decrease your frame size by setting the minimum and preferred size, then calling `pack()` on your JFrame. Also check that the resize event is getting the correct sizes (Both bigger and smaller).

Comment: I now see these errors, even with smaller window sizes:
2015-09-17 14:03:39.052 java[684:10562] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:298)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:98)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:324)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:234)
...
CoreAnimation: 10000 by 1978 image is too large for GPU, ignoring

This seems odd since it's possible to span non-Java apps across all monitors.

Comment: Ok, this is a JDK bug, you will need to update your JDK/JRE. It was fixed in JDK 7u67 b34 and newer, or if you use Java 8 then it should also be fixed in the latest version 'JDK 8u60'. Specific bug info: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055839

Comment: Just an addition to the previous comment: Open JDK fixed it in 7u67 b34 and newer, while I don't think oracle got it until 7u85 b1

Comment: I just installed the latest JDK (1.8.0_60), and I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: I just realized that I was not setting the location to 0,0 anymore. (I changed it to 800,800, but compensated for this by specifying the size as 10000,2000) so that it could still be drawn.) Changing it back to 0,0 gave me these errors:
'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:299)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:99)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:325)
 at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:229)'

Comment: This is a bit of a mystery, I was able to run the code in my answer above in OSX 10.10.1, compiled with jdk1.7.0_51 from Netbeans 8.0.2 and it worked perfectly with no errors and showing the correct window size of 10240x3200. Double check your environment and make sure you don't have any other versions of java installed, or make sure you use the correct JRE by using the full path to the JRE/JDK when running the test piece of code. Just to check: Are you running the small code snippet only? You could actually be running out of memory, what are the specs of your machine?

Comment: The specs for my machine are listed in the original question. I know that when I updated the JDK, the latest one was set to the default when running things from the command line (which is what I have been doing for the test snippet). I'd honestly be really surprised if I was running out of memory since I have 16GB of memory and usually only run a couple of applications at a time (e.g. Eclipse, Chrome, a terminal window to run the test snippet, and maybe a Word document).

Comment: The GT 120 is quite an underpowered GPU, it will struggle to support the full resolution you are throwing at it on most programs, and more so when using java. As a test can you run the same code with just a single monitor plugged in? It will still draw the rest of the window off screen and will give you an indication to how your GPU is coping. Also if you havn't already tried it: set a much much higher XmS and XmX when you launch your app.

Comment: I tried using a single monitor and running the code, even with ridiculously large Xms and Xmx (e.g. 10g), and I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: Because I am unable to reproduce the issue on my slow mac mini we can only assume that 1) your system is unable to handle the task; or 2) Your java environment is not configured or setup correctly. Have you ever changed any java settings? Also please open terminal and enter `java -version` make sure it shows the version you installed `1.8.0_60` and it should be the 64bit edition. If the version info is correct then you need to test the code snippet on another newer mac (With the newer version of Java) and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I do have Java version 1.8.0_60 64-bit, along with the latest JDK and Mac OS version. I don't have any other Macs to test with though, so I'm not sure where that leaves debugging this bizarre issue.